# Convert table to key-value pair with plain JS

Tags: javascript

I have a large table consisting of row numbers and prices. I want to be able to look up a price by using the row number.

[image]

```
function buildtable(){

   var tableObj = document.getElementById( 'table' );

   var allTRs = tableObj.getElementsByTagName( 'tr' );
   for ( var trCounter = 0; trCounter < allTRs.length; trCounter++ )
   {
     var tmpArr = [];
     var allTDsInTR = allTRs[ trCounter ].getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
     for ( var tdCounter = 0; tdCounter < allTDsInTR.length - 1; tdCounter++ )
     {
       tmpArr.push( allTDsInTR[ tdCounter ].innerHTML );
     }
     arr.push( tmpArr );

  }

}
```

the following code creates a list of lists.

[image]

How can I change the function so its creates a single key pair store?

HTML FOR TABLE

foreach($res as $row) {

```
  $seat = $row['RowNumber'];  
  $price = $row['Zone.PriceMultiplier * 15.00'];

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$seat."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$price."</td>";
   echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value=\"$seat;\" onclick='javatest(this);' </td>";
   echo "</tr>";


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object as the key-value map (hash table).

```js
function buildtable() {
    var tableObj = document.getElementById('table');
    var map = {};
    var allTRs = tableObj.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var trCounter = 1; trCounter < allTRs.length; trCounter++) {
        var tmpArr = [];
        var allTDsInTR = allTRs[trCounter].getElementsByTagName('td');
    
        if (allTDsInTR.length) {
           map[allTDsInTR[0].innerHTML.trim()] = parseFloat(allTDsInTR[1].innerHTML.trim());
        }
    }
    
    console.log(map);

}

buildtable();
```

```html
<table id='table'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            RowNumber
        </td>
        <td>
            Price
        </td>
    <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            U01
        </td>
        <td>
            24.5
        </td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            U02
        </td>
        <td>
            22
        </td>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result will be something like:

```
{
  "U01": 24.5,
  "U02": 22
}
```

Comment: this looks just right but im getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined, i was getting the same issue when attempting a similar solution earlier.

Comment: map[allTDsInTR[0].innerHTML.trim()] working but parseFloat(allTDsInTR[1].innerHTML.trim()) is not

Comment: Did you wrap your logic around the condition `if (allTDsInTR.length)`? Also, can you provide the HTML for your table?

Comment: got it working without the parseFloat, map[allTDsInTR[0].innerHTML.trim()] = allTDsInTR[1].innerHTML.trim();

Comment: That's great to hear, @Gooze_Berry!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var tableRows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#myTable > tbody > tr'));
var result = {};
tableRows.forEach(row => {
  var cols = Array.from(row.getElementsByTagName('td'));
  var key = cols[0].innerHTML;
  var value = cols[1].innerHTML;
  if (!result[key]) {
    result[key] = [value];
  } else {
    result[key].push(value);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>RowNumber</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>U01</td>
      <td>26.999999284744263</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>U02</td>
      <td>26.999999284744263</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>U01</td>
      <td>26.999999284744263</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: getting the same issue as the answer above,  var value = cols[1].innerHTML; Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined.

Comment: @Gooze_Berry you should add your actual table to the question, i would guess something is wrong with it, as you can see, Clicking `Run code snipper` gets the results expected.